# Determine days of week from bit mask

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, bitmask

I am working with a third party application and am trying to extract meaningful information about shift information based on the data.

```
shift_pattern_start_dt     pattern
2014-05-27                 1111000
2015-10-25                 1110011
```

`2014-05-27` is a `Tuesday` the start position of the pattern is `Tuesday`.  So I would want the results to show `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, and `Friday`.

`2015-10-25` is a `Sunday` the start position of this pattern is `Sunday`. The results should be `Sunday`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Friday`, and `Saturday`.

Any ideas or suggestions to determine the correct working days?

Comment: You just gotta love "creative" programmers....

Comment: @Igor: I love them with a sharp stick in the eye.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (shift_pattern_start_dt date, pattern varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2014-05-27','1111000'),
('2015-10-25','1110011')

Select *
      ,NewCol = concat(
                IIF(substring(pattern,1,1)='1',   +DateName(WEEKDAY,shift_pattern_start_dt),'')
               ,IIF(substring(pattern,2,1)='1',','+DateName(WEEKDAY,dateadd(DAY,1,shift_pattern_start_dt)),null)
               ,IIF(substring(pattern,3,1)='1',','+DateName(WEEKDAY,dateadd(DAY,2,shift_pattern_start_dt)),null)
               ,IIF(substring(pattern,4,1)='1',','+DateName(WEEKDAY,dateadd(DAY,3,shift_pattern_start_dt)),null)
               ,IIF(substring(pattern,5,1)='1',','+DateName(WEEKDAY,dateadd(DAY,4,shift_pattern_start_dt)),null)
               ,IIF(substring(pattern,6,1)='1',','+DateName(WEEKDAY,dateadd(DAY,5,shift_pattern_start_dt)),null)
               ,IIF(substring(pattern,7,1)='1',','+DateName(WEEKDAY,dateadd(DAY,6,shift_pattern_start_dt)),null)
               )
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
shift_pattern_start_dt  pattern   NewCol
2014-05-27              1111000   Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
2015-10-25              1110011   Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Friday,Saturday
```

> **EDIT - Cross Apply Version**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select NewCol =Stuff((Select ',' +D 
                  From (
                        Select N,D = IIF(substring(A.pattern,N,1)='0',null,DateName(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(DAY,N-1,A.shift_pattern_start_dt)))
                         From (Values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) N(N)             
                        ) B1 
                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
             ) B
```

> **Execution Plan for Concat() Approach**

[image]

> **Execution Plan for Cross Apply Approach**

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution but can be improved - consider cross apply to reduce code repitition.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Actually that was my first thought, and was going to post "Option A & B", but decided to play it simple  :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled DRY?  Not familiar with that one

Comment: DRY = **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself. In a nut shell, if you find (much) repetition its time to refactor to modules/methods (*whatever is appropriate*) and call to the abstract/refactored code (*basically try to reuse instead of repeat*). Also, that is a great answer (*I was the first upvoter :)*)

Comment: I would love to see the Cross Apply solution as well!!

Comment: @Leslie The average of 5 runs each using 50,000 records.  The average of first approach was 327 ms while the second had a average of 602 ms

Comment: @Leslie a cte approach was over 970 ms

Comment: Thanks for showing the cross apply approach!  I was more interested just to see how that would work but appreciate the performance analysis.